# How to fix the height of a div and add a scroll bar to it?

Tags: scroll, scrollbar

I'm trying to fix the height of the 'main body of text' div and add a scrollbar so that everything stays on one page.

I'm a beginner with this and have tried to follow an array of different instructions on different websites but nothing has worked and would just like some very nice person to break it down for me!

Answer (score 1):

you mus set the syle of the div in this way:

```
<div style="width:191px; height:190px; overflow:auto;" ..>text</div>
```

the attribute "overflow" set the scrollbal if the div contenent is to large.